# Moto G Lollipop update

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g, emoticons

I'm in Ireland and recently got the Lollipop update for my Moto G. Ever since then although the emoji's appear and I send them the people receive the messages but with no emoji's attached is anyone having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to message settings, SMS Encoding Method, set to **Automatic**

This worked for me